# How to share LESS or CSS files in Angular 7 application?

Tags: css, angular, less, angular7

On the src root of an Angular 7 application I have 3 less files:

```
styles.less (global styles)
constants.less (less constants like colors, fonts, ...)
reset.less (css reset)
```

And I have the following on angular.json under build:

```
"styles": [
  "src/resets.less",
  "src/constants.less",
  "src/styles.less"
]
```

In styles.less, to use constants, I needed to add the following:

```
@import (reference) 'constants.less';
```

The problem is how to use the constants inside a component's less files?

As an example let me show a HomeComponent (home.component.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.less']
})

export class HomeComponent {
}
```

To use the constants.less I need to add to home.component.less the following:

```
@import (reference) './../../constants.less';
```

This makes it work but I have a few questions:

1. Can I reference constants.less somehow without './../..'?
2. Should I load constants.less in HomeComponent styleUrls?
3. Should I move constants.less to a shared folder instead of having in src root?
   I placed it there because styles.less is in src root and is using it.
   So I though I needed to load it using the angular.json definition file.

Comment: #1 option - you can try tilde `~` operator, the project root reference. #2 idk, #3 you shouldn't, it has to stay private, `webpack` will post-process it later. Actually, you've to build `less` theme then import it to `styles.less`. Components won't see it without explicit imports or disabled view encapsulation.